# How to generate unique alphanumeric ID 11 characters long in java

Tags: java

I need to work on a framework for Unique ID generation. Currently, a reference number is 11 characters with 5 characters Julian date, 6th character specific to a datacenter and other 5 - uniquely generated sequence of alpha characters. This make the algorithm to generate 20 million unique records.

I do not want UUID format. Need a more readable format potentially with composition of a date that can represent when it's generated and uniquely generated characters/numbers.

Just wanted to go over the potential algorithms.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Use [`java.util.UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) or [hashid](https://hashids.org/java/).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You explained your desired composition, so what is keeping you from implementing it?

Comment: The problem is that I tried UUID but it's in xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx but that does not work for 11 chars long and need a readable format. Just needed potential algorithms/frameworks to solve this.

Comment: a UUID will always have 32 letters

Comment: what you want is the RandomString from apache commons which accepts a variable length: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: yes, I want it for a fixed length of 11 chars. All the numbers need to be unique. what are the frameworks that I can use to create all unique numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, unlikely to be very unique.

**UUID** is unbeatable but verbose (database/java). It gives 128 bits. Encode those with URL-safe **Base64** and you get **22** almost alphanumeric chars (with two extras like `-` `_`).

Rolling your own: `System.nanos()`.